# java step definitions not found in multiple files - only in one

Tags: cucumber-jvm, intellij-14, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have a project in Intellij, with step definitions spread over several classes. When I run my feature file, it will find the first step definition, but not the other ones (they are in a different class). If I move the other step definitions to that same class as the first step, then it finds them... 
I'm certain that step definitions for one feature file don't have to be in one single java class, ie it is possible to have step definitions spread over different classes. What am I missing?

[image: Here is the project structure and runner:]

Comment: I tried glue = "steps/com/dms" as well, same result. The only way I can get all the step definition of my feature file recognized is by moving all of them to the setup

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. Somehow the other classes didn't have the public keyword. This is a project moved from groovy to java, so the keyword wasn't needed in groovy and got forgotten in the transfer.